# Automatically bold first sentence of a floats caption

Tags: formatting, captions, bold

How to bold automatically the first sentence of the float caption and second sentence is normal?

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\caption{First sentence. Second sentence.}
\end{figure}
```

Output should be:

**Figure 1. First sentence.** Second sentence.

Comment: Do you use any packages influencing the caption? Which document class do you use? Please provide a complete minimal working examples.

Comment: I did not use any influencing packages. I use article.cls

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the approach described in [Customize text format of captions by parsing content of \@caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65768/customize-text-format-of-captions-by-parsing-content-of-caption#comment140083_65768), namelly

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,tableposition=top}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\formatlabel[1]{%
    \noexpandarg
    \IfSubStr{#1}{.}{%
      \StrBefore{#1}{.}[\firstcaption]%
      \StrBehind{#1}{.}[\secondcaption]%
      \textbf{\firstcaption.} \secondcaption}{%
      #1}%
      }


\patchcmd{\@caption}{#3}{\formatlabel{#3}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
test test
\caption{First sentence. Second sentence.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution only works when your sentence ends with a (single) period.

Answer (score 14):

A non-automatic way would be to define:

```
\newcommand{\bcaption}[2]{\caption{\textbf{#1} #2}}
```

and using the 'bf' option to the package caption.

Here a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bf]{caption}
\newcommand{\bcaption}[2]{\caption{\textbf{#1} #2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
 \bcaption{First sentence.}{Second sentence.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice advantage: You can use this to have the bold first sentence as the short LoF/LoT entry. Just use `\newcommand{\bcaption}[2]{\caption[#1]{\textbf{#1} #2}}`

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @guido's [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65788/49837), I ended up with the following:

```tex
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand\firstsentencebold[1]{%
    \noexpandarg
    \exploregroups
    \IfSubStr{#1}{. }{%
        \StrBefore{#1}{. }[\firstcaptionsentence]%
        \StrBehind{#1}{. }[\othercaptionsentences]%
        \textbf{\firstcaptionsentence. }\othercaptionsentences%
    }{%
        \textbf{#1.}%
    }%
}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{FirstSentenceBold}{\textbf{#1#2}\firstsentencebold{#3}}
\captionsetup{format=FirstSentenceBold}
```

It's mostly for my future self.