# Customize text format of captions by parsing content of \@caption

Tags: spacing, captions, xstring

I need the first sentence of my captions to appear on its own line in a \large, bold font.  I also need to same document to easily produce standard captions (all same font, no line breaks).  I have implemented a class file that uses an option to directly modify \@caption and add the necessary formatting; however, my code isn't quite working.  This example correctly places the first sentence of the caption on its own line in the correct font, but the text is not left-aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,labelsep=newline,tableposition=top}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\formatlabel[1]{%
    \noexpandarg
    \StrBefore{#1}{.}[\firstcaption] %
    \StrBehind{#1}{.}[\secondcaption] %
    \textbf{\large\firstcaption}
    \\
    \secondcaption}

\patchcmd{\@caption}{#3}{\formatlabel{#3}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{A Simple table. It has a caption with multiple sentences. It has a caption with multiple sentences. It has a caption with multiple sentences.}
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: removing the spaces before the comments in `\StrBefore{#1}{.}[\firstcaption] %`  and `\StrBehind{#1}{.}[\secondcaption] %` should fix the problem.

Comment: @Guido you could turn you comment into an answer (maybe showing the corrected code and an image of the result?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indentation is given by the two spaces before the comments in

```
\StrBefore{#1}{.}[\firstcaption] %
```

and

```
\StrBehind{#1}{.}[\secondcaption] %
```

Removing them fixes the problem. Also you can add a condition to ensure there is period `.` in the caption.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\formatlabel[1]{%
    \noexpandarg
    \IfSubStr{#1}{.}{%
      \StrBefore{#1}{.}[\firstcaption]%
      \StrBehind{#1}{.}[\secondcaption]%
      \textbf{\large\firstcaption.}\\\secondcaption}{%
      \textbf{\large #1}}%
      }

\patchcmd{\@caption}{#3}{\formatlabel{#3}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Removing the spaces does the trick.  The additional condition to check for a period is also a great suggestion.