# Automatically bolded first sencence of caption in listoffigures

Tags: captions

I have used the following approach to automatically make the first sentence of a float caption bold (in combination with hyperref): [Hyperref compatability with automatically bolded first sentence of float caption float](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242189/hyperref-compatability-with-automatically-bolded-first-sentence-of-float-caption).

However, additionally I also need to have a short version of the caption in my list of figures / list of tables (as most of my captions are very long). The usual way with `\caption[entry in LOF]{full caption}` does not work anymore. Is there a possibility to automatically depict the bold part of the caption in the LOF/LOT?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\formatlabel[1]{%
    \noexpandarg
    \IfSubStr{#1}{.}{%
      \StrBefore{#1}{.}[\firstcaption]%
      \StrBehind{#1}{.}[\secondcaption]%
      \textbf{\firstcaption.} \secondcaption}{%
      #1}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newcommand*{\org@caption}{}%
  \let\org@caption\@caption
  \def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%  
    \org@caption{#1}[{#2}]{\formatlabel{#3}}%
  }%
}   
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tb]
  \caption{First sentence is bold. Second sentence is not.}
  \label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adapted [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269444/151808) to set the bold part as short description.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\getfirst#1.#2\relax{{#1}}
\def\getsecond#1.#2\relax{{#2}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \newcommand*{\org@caption}{}%
    \let\org@caption\@caption
    \def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%  
        \org@caption{#1}[\getfirst#3\relax]{{\bfseries\getfirst#3\relax} \getsecond#3\relax}%
    }%
} 

\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[tb]
        \caption{First sentence is bold. Second sentence is not.}
        \label{fig:figure1}
    \end{figure}
    \listoffigures
\end{document}
```