# Automatic way to use the first sentence of the figure caption as the short caption

Tags: captions

Is there any automatic way to use the first sentence of a caption as the short caption to be displayed in table of contents?
Precisely I want to write:
`\caption{First Sentence. Second Sentence.}` to be compiled as: `\caption[First Sentence]{First Sentence. Second Sentence.}`
After the first sentence I don't have necessary just one sentence.

Comment: Is enough automatic some like `\Caption{First sentence}{Second sentence}` ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I have written my long report and now I find out that I should rewrite the first sentence of each caption for list of figures. I need a way to not change every of the caption commands.

Comment: It would be possible using TeX's general parameter parsing mechanism.  But it would be easier to suggest something appropriate if you provided us with a MWE to work on.  I take it from your comment that you need a quick hack rather than a general mechanism, and that you can't simply use your editor to make some global changes to your `caption`s?

Comment: Yes its true. Also, I think its too commonplace for scientific texts that the first sentence of captions is also the title of figure that would be shown in table of figures and a new caption code with this feature may save time in writing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a quick-and-dirty hack, try this in your pre-amble:

```
\let\oldcaption\caption
\def\splitter #1. #2@@{\oldcaption[#1]{#1. #2}}
\def\caption#1{\splitter #1@@}
```

but beware that I'm assuming you have a very simple environment.

Comment: Thanks; it works by adding just before \begin{document}, after adding babel package. I think your code is also a quick answer to this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65680/automatically-bold-first-sentence-of-a-floats-caption?rq=1 by changing your second line with: \def\splitter #1. #2@@{\oldcaption[#1]{\textbf{#1}. #2}}

Comment: Does not work with subcaption: `! Package caption Error: The 'subcaption' package does not work correctly in compatibility mode.` Is there a more reliable option?

Comment: @user877329, as I said, I was assuming a very simple environment...

Comment: This is great thank you. For anyone who wants to use this in a document that has some one sentence captions already be sure to add a space after the full-stop in order for the code to function correctly across the document.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote all your labels directly after caption as I do:

```bash
sed 's/\(\\caption\){\(\\label{[^}]\+}\)\([^.]*\)\.\(.\+\)/\1[\3]{\2\3. \4/' report.tex
```

This works in some cases. It uses the GNU sed extension `\+` otherwise it matches to much.