# Limit the title in \listoffigures to the first sentence of the caption

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, pandoc

I would like to do the same thing as described here : [Automatic way to use the first sentence of the figure caption as the short caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243982/automatic-way-to-use-the-first-sentence-of-the-figure-caption-as-the-short-capti).

Which mean that I need to limit the title of the figures in `\listoffigures` to the first sentence of the caption.

The solution provided in the question above try to split the caption with `.` and only insert the first part of the list as a title. It does not work for me and I don't have the Latex skills to tweak and make it work the piece of code.

The solution was to add this :

```
\let\oldcaption\caption
\def\splitter #1. #2@@{\oldcaption[#1]{#1. #2}}
\def\caption#1{\splitter #1@@}
```

Because I use Pandoc and a Markdown syntax I can't use the latex syntax and then use the short caption mechanism.

Linked to https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2417

Comment: Have you seen the `--parse-raw` flag for pandoc? It looks like it may solve your problem by allowing you to put raw LaTeX into your markdown document. http://pandoc.org/README.html

Comment: That's not the problem here because I use a `preamble.text` where I put some custom Latex command. I inserted in this file the solution provided but the previous question but it does not work as I said.

Comment: Could you answer your own question @HadiM? It is not clear how you solved it! Where did you add those lines?